# How to fill a ListView using textbox from an other form window and events

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, events

I found a lot of tutorials and questions about this subject but I can't make it work because I want to use an event to add my data. I don't want to recreate a window each time I add some content.

So I have a `Form1` with the `ListView1` and a button "Add Issue" which opens `Form2`.

On `Form2` I have two textbox : `Issue` and `Comment` and a `submit` button. When the user press the button I want the data of the `Form2` to fill the `Listview1` (first time the first line, second time the second line...)

If you have any tips or any links specifically about events, everything can be usefull !

Comment: set the listview `modifier` to `public` and control it from another winform

Comment: or set the form2 textboxes `modifier` to `public` and get it from `winform1` after `ShowDialog` closed

Comment: But i will have to make a `new Form2()` each time i add data, no ?

Comment: yes, you can use `Form2 f = new Form2` and `if(f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)` and then, get the textboxes values by `f.textbox1.Text` if the textbox1 `modifier` was `public`

Comment: Unfortunatly i can't use `new Form2()` each time, i need an event when clicking the submit button

Comment: Ok, you should edit your question, then...

Comment: done ! sorry and thanks for your answers anyway !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this in an event driven way, you need to:

Declare an event args class that will hold the inserted data:

```
public class ItemAddedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public ItemAddedEventArgs(string issue, string comment)
    {
        Issue = issue;
        Comment = comment;
    }

    public string Issue { get; private set; }
    public string Comment { get; private set; }
}
```

Declare an event in `Form2` that will be triggered when pressing `Submit` button:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public event EventHandler<ItemAddedEventArgs> ItemAdded;

    private void OnSubmitButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var args = new ItemAddedEventArgs(
            issue: textBoxIssue.Text,
            comment: textBoxComment.Text);
        ItemAdded(this, args);
    }
}
```

In `Form1` subscribe to `ItemAdded` event when you create an instance of `Form2` and unsubscribe to it when disposing that instance:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Form2 form2;

    public Form1()
    {
        form2 = new Form2();
        form2.ItemAdded += OnItemAdded;
        form2.Disposed += (sender, args) => form2.ItemAdded -= OnItemAdded;
    }

    private void OnItemAdded(object sender, ItemAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        listview1.Items.Add(new Item(e.Issue, e.Comment));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot ! that almost work but i have a `System.NullReferenceException` on `ItemAdded(this, args);` (last line form two) any ideas ?

Comment: This may be due to `ItemAdded` event being raised when there are no handlers registered to it. Check if `ItemAdded` is not null; if it is, then make sure you add the handler to it before loading the form.

Comment: `ItemAdded` is null but i don't find the way to add the handler to it :/

Comment: I don't get it :/ sorry, and thanks again for helping me !

Comment: @Babuh, please see an example app here https://github.com/RePierre/stackoverflow/tree/master/36742935

Answer (score 0):

If you use something like `ShowDialog()` for `form2`, and then refresh your listbox data on `DialogResult.OK`.

Something like this on form1:

```
if (new form2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // rebind data to the ListBox
}
```

Comment: does it mean i have to create a new `form2` each time i add a line ?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by each time. You could open form2 and have the submit button just add new data, then clear the fields, and perform the rebinding on closing form2 only. Or you can have the submit button click close the form2 and update the ListBox each time. Depends on which works for you really.

Answer (score 0):

**Semi singleton senario**

***Creating a field on `Form1` class***:

```
Form2 f;
```

***Initialize it***: in the `Form_Load` event, you should initize the `f` variable.

```
f = new Form2();
```

***Create a function to append an item to Listview***: in the `Form1` class you should create this function:

```
private void AppendItem(string issue, string comment)
{ .... }
```

***Handle the Clicking of Add Issue button***:

```
private void AddIssueClicked(object sender,EventArgs e)
{ 
    if(f.ShowDialog == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        AppendData(f.textbox1.Text, f.textbox2.Text);
        f.textbox1.Text = f.textbox2.Text = "";
    } 
}
```

***Close the `Form2` when clicking on the Submit button by `DialogResult.OK`***: set the `DialogResult` property of `Submit` Button to `OK`